# Extrair parte do texto em uma variavel

Tags: string, script, powershell, substring

Estou criando um script para fazer backup de alguns diretórios via powershell, porém para um determinado diretório, eu quero acessar um arquivo, ler uma linha e retornar uma string com parte da linha.

Arquivo XPTO tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
;===============================================================
;--------------------AMBIENTE DE PRODUÇÃO-----------------------
;===============================================================

[C4P12LEAD]
SourcePath=E:\Outsourcing\Clientes\c4p12lead\apo\20180828
RootPath=E:\Outsourcing\Clientes\c4p12lead\protheus-data
CtreeRootPath=E:\Outsourcing\Clientes\c4p12lead\protheus-data
StartPath=\system\
x2_path=
RpoDb=top
RpoLanguage=por
RpoVersion=120
LocalFiles=ctree
Trace=0
```

Preciso retornar o caminho da linha que contém o SourcePath:
`SourcePath =E:\Outsourcing\Clientes\c4p12lead\apo\20180828`

E colocar esse caminho em uma variavel SourveApo: 
`E:\Outsourcing\Clientes\c4p12lead\apo\20180828`

No fim do processo a variavel $SourveApo precisa ter o conteúdo `E:\Outsourcing\Clientes\c4p12lead\apo\20180828`

Como farei isso?

Answer (score 1):

Quebre o texto em linhas, procure por sua tag e depois pegue o valor por posição de texto.

```
$text = "
;===============================================================
;--------------------AMBIENTE DE PRODUÇÃO-----------------------
;===============================================================

[C4P12LEAD]
SourcePath=E:\Outsourcing\Clientes\c4p12lead\apo\20180828
RootPath=E:\Outsourcing\Clientes\c4p12lead\protheus-data
CtreeRootPath=E:\Outsourcing\Clientes\c4p12lead\protheus-data
StartPath=\system\
x2_path=
RpoDb=top
RpoLanguage=por
RpoVersion=120
LocalFiles=ctree
Trace=0";

$token="SourcePath"
$extractedValue = (($text -split [System.Environment]::NewLine) | where { $_ -Like "$token*" }).Substring("$token=".Length);
Write-Host $extractedValue
```

Comment: Obrigado Bruno.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.